# Limit of a sequence (Can't make sure my solution is correct)

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, proof-verification

Can you please explain me the right way of computing $\lim \limits _{n \to \infty} \frac {(a-1)^n} {a^{n-1}}$ for $a \ge 1$ if my answer doesn't seem to be right?

(My answer: $\lim \limits _{n \to \infty} \frac {(a-1)^n} {a^{n-1}} = \lim \limits _{n \to \infty} \frac {a^n + \dots} {a^n a^{-1}} = \lim \limits _{n \to \infty} \frac {a^n} {a^{n-1}} = \frac 1 {a^{-1}} = a$.)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{(a-1)^n}{a^{(n-1)}}=\lim_{n\to \infty}a\frac{(a-1)^n}{a^{n}}=\lim_{n\to \infty}a\left(\frac{a-1}a\right)^n=a*0=0$$